# Ubuntu 18.04 and Behringer UCA222, cannot control recording level in Audacity

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, audacity

on a Dell Inspiron with previous versions of Ubuntu I've had no problem, but with the latest Ubuntu I cannot control record volume from a Behringer UCA222 in Audacity.  The USB device appears in Audacity's list of inputs, and if I select it, and start recording in Ubuntu, I can record at a fixed level.  If I simultaneously open pavu2 it says there are no applications currently recording, and consequently have no control of the recording level.  The recording level control in Audacity also has no effect.
It's kinda half working, but its as if the UCA222 han't been properly installed.  I can get the relevant excerpt from dmesg if it would help, along with any screen capture?  I've tried Xubuntu 18.04, Mint and Studio and they all behave the same.
Any pointers?

Comment: Is the USB device shown as an ALSA device in Audacity? is there another device option "Pulse"?